# How to retrieve model ID when creating new?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Using Backbone.JS, I am able to successfully create new models and save them to the server.  They successfully make an ajax call and the subscribed UI elements update appropriately.  The problem I then run into is that I don't know the ID of the newly created object.

I can see in the response headers for my create calls, that the sever is returning a location header like:  `Location   https://localhost/rest/beta/mobile/footer/OTo3Njow` with the last parameter being the newly created ID.

How can I get this ID without overriding backbone.sync?  If I have to override backbone.sync, what is the cleanest method?

**UPDATE**
It looks like my organization is using an older Backbone.js in which the parse method of models does not provide a reference to the XHR object, otherwise I could catch the ID and do the assigning there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The server should send back a JSON object containing the `id` of the model, plus any other attributes that it wants to update. If it does, Backbone will automatically grab the id.

If that's not an option, you should override `Backbone.sync`, because then your API (which communicates the new id in the location header instead of the response body) doesn’t conform to what Backbone supports out of the box.

---

If the server already does this, and you just want to get at the id, it depends on who needs to know. If it’s the code calling `model.save()`, then it can pass in a success callback:

```
model.save({}, {
    success: function(){
        // do something with model.id
    }
});
```

If the model itself needs to be notified when it gets an id, you can use an initializer:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.bind("change:id", function(){
            // …
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by overloading the success param in backbone.sync

```
// Return XHR on success
params.success = function(response, text, XHR) {
  if(_.isFunction(model.xhrParse)) { model.xhrParse.call(model, response, XHR); }
  success.call(model, response);
}
```

and by adding a new method to my base model "xhrParse":

```
xhrParse: function(resp, XHR) {
   var locationHeader = XHR.getResponseHeader('Location');
   if(locationHeader && !this.id) {
     var xplode = locationHeader.split("/");
     this.id = xplode[xplode.length - 1];
   }
   return resp;
 }
```

Comment: Use `this.set('id', …)`. When a model’s id changes, other things need to happen — the id is updated in the model's attributes object, if the model is in a collection the collection needs to be notified that it has an id, etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-id

The model.id property?

Comment: This does get set on elements returned from model.fetch() but it isn't getting set on myNewModel.save()